# Significant difference within line set and between two sets of lines

Tags: spss, t-test, matlab, paired-comparisons

For my research a person has walked on a treadmill which contains two pressure plates: One below the left foot, one below the right. I would like to compare the force in the z (downwards) direction between the left and the right plate. Below is an image of 34 steps of the Left foot. Each step consists of 2000 till 3000 samples (2-3 seconds @ 0.5 Km/h) and has a height of about 85Kg. The step length between left and right for a consecutive step differs as well.

[image: 34 steps on a treadmill with pressure plates]

Using 34 steps in the Left set, and 34 steps in the Right set:

1) Is it possible to calculate if one of the steps within the Left set, is significantly different from the others in the Left set?

2) Is it possible to calculate if the “Left set”, differs significantly from the "Right set"? Do I need the same amount of steps in both sets (e.g. 34 steps)?

Besides analysing the whole graphic, I would like to analyse specific data like: surface under the curve, height, ascending slope and width.

3) If I have 34 slopes, can I calculate if one of them differs significantly (i.e. significance within one set)?

4) When I compare the 34 slopes of the “Left set” with the “Right set”, can I use the Student's paired t-test? Assuming I use consecutive steps of left and right? Or can I use another method?

I am working in Matlab, but I have access to SPSS as well.

Thank you!

Comment: After allot of searching I have not found a method to validate within a group (Q1 and Q3), hence I guess thats not going to happen. Regarding Q2 the only option I have found so far is Crosscorrelation. For Q4 I haven't found anthing else than paired t-test, since the data seems normally distributed I hope its allowed to use that method.